# Why isn't this react component updating with mobx observer

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I'm trying to use the ObservableMap (also tried observable.map). I would expect the following minimal component setup to update when i add an item to my devices. Am I doing something incorrectly or misunderstanding mobx? Both console.logs will output `{next: ƒ, Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ}` and doesn't show any data for my map.

```ts
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { observer, Provider } from 'mobx-react';
import { ObservableMap, observable } from 'mobx';
declare var Map;

const App = observer(
    ['devices', 'store'],
    ({devices, store}) => {

        console.log(store.devices.entries());

        return <div>
            {[...devices.entries()].map(([id, device]) => <div>test</div>)}
            {/* {devices.entries().map(([id, device]) => <div key={device.id}>{device.name}</div>)} */}
            test3
        </div>
})

var test = observable({
    devices: new Map([['a', 'one']])
});

setTimeout(() => test.devices.set('b', "two"), 200);

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={test} devices={test.devices}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Which version of `mobx` do you use? Do you get some errors in console? With `mobx@3.6.2` I've been able to make your example work, I only change the function inside the `map`: `([id, device]) => <div key={id}>{device}</div>)` to match your example data

Comment: I'm using version 4.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't move to version 4 and above yet.
But what I understand is that `ObservableMap` doesn't exist anymore and you should use `observable.map`. And in your case that make the entire object `observable` you can just use es6 native `Map`:

```
var test = observable({ devices: new Map([['a', 'one']]) });
```

And now that you have just a `Map` `enteries` is an iterator so you can use spread operator or `Array.from` to use array `map` function:

```
<div>
  {Array.from(devices.entries()).map(([id, device]) => (
    <div key={id}>{device}</div>
  ))}
  test3
</div>
```

Comment: i've tried observable.map but I will try adding a Map polyfil and do it this way and get back to you.

Comment: `var test = observable({ devices: observable.map([['a', 'one']]) });` also works

Comment: tried with new Map and i'm still not getting any values in my component

Comment: Did you use spread operator? if it's still not working, can you update your code and any errors in the console if you have?

Comment: i get `devices.entries(...).slice is not a function` updated the code above

Comment: even if i do a test.devices.keys() immediately after creating the observable i don't get the keys.

Comment: a lil bit out of the scope of the original question, but, what browser are you using and do you use some transpiler like babel?

Comment: chrome and webpack

Comment: interesting `setTimeout(() => console.log(test.devices.get('b'), test.devices.keys()), 2000)` will produce the value for b but not the keys.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168681/discussion-between-doron-brikman-and-matthewdaniel).